# How to save and read user information (username ,password,and so on) to a excel?

Tags: java, excel

Note:     each information is a **String** !

Comment: we gonna need more info.  what techs are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with libraries such as [JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/), but... it is a VERY bad idea to store this kind of information in excel spreadsheet.